# Regex - Start of String and End of String Anchors For Single Character Clause

Tags: php, regex

Sorry for the NOOB factor but what are these two regi (regex plural lol) doing differently?

http://codepad.viper-7.com/vaQTMh

```
    <?php

    $name = 'BartSimpson';
    $regex1 = '#^[A-Z]$#i';
    $regex2 = '#[A-Z]#i';


    if (preg_match($regex1, $name)) {
        echo "A match was found.";
    } else {
        echo "A match was not found.";
    }


    if (preg_match($regex2, $name)) {
        echo "A match was found.";
    } else {
        echo "A match was not found.";
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: +1. Noob questions are great, as long as they're asked clearly (which this one definitely is).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one has, as you have noted, start/end of string anchors. So it will only match if the string you give it contains *exactly one* character in the range `[A-Z]`.

The second, having no anchors, matches a string that contains *at least one* character in the range `[A-Z]`, anywhere in its contents.

Please spend some time reading about regular expressions (for example here http://www.regular-expressions.info/). This is very basic.

Comment: That's correct, just note that it's not always 'at least one' and 'exactly one', just in this case. It should be explained that the start/end anchors force the string to begin with the start of that regex rule and end with what's at the end of it; meaning it can't contain anything outside (for example, `/[\d]+/` will match `a12a3s` but `/^[\d]+$/` would only match 123 or 389 for example

Answer (score 0):

Both are same in case of `$name = 'BartSimpson';`

But if the string would be something like "1BartSimpson" then regex1 will not match because it expects [A-Z] from the start of the string to the end. "^" denotes start of string and "$" means end of string.

EDIT: This answer (above this edit) is incorrect. I missed that there needs to be a "+" as in "^[A-Z]+$" for it to match "BartSimpson". Thanks for corrections.

Comment: the first won't match `$name`

Comment: I missed that there needs to be a "+" as in "^[A-Z]+$" for it to match "BartSimpson". Thanks for corrections.

Answer (score 0):

1. `(?i)^[A-Z]$`: beginning of line or string, character [A-Za-z], end of line or string
2. `(?i)[A-Z]`: character [A-Za-z]

So 1st regex shouldn't match `BartSimpson`, while 2nd must.

Answer (score 0):

First one, will make sure your string contains *only* one `A` to `Z` throughout the whole string.

Second one, will check if your string has *at least* one of the `A` to `Z` letters.